# Load a list into memory with python? or is it already in the memory?

Tags: python, arrays, list, pickle, stringio

I'm writing a program that opens a database file saved with pickle.
but if i want to load the list from the file into the memory with StringIO/cStringIO it says:

```
Opening database...
Loading database into memory...
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "C:\myfile.py", line 17 in open_database
    database.write(databasefile)
TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not list
```

This is my code:

```
def open_database(self):
    print("Opening database...")
    databasefile = open('database.dat', "r")
    databasecontent = cPickle.load(databasefile)
    databasefile.close()
    print('Loading database into memory...')
    database = cStringIO.StringIO()
    database.write(databasecontent)
    atexit.register(close_database)
```

Comment: "TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not list" ... "not *list*" ... "**list**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already in memory. Loading a pickle returns a python structure.

Moreover, a `StringIO` object is a in-memory file-like object, not a Python object structure. You cannot take the in-memory representation of a python structure and 'write' it into memory, you instruct the Python interpreter to construct those objects for you (which is what the `pickle` module does for you).

Last but not least, you really should avoid using `atexit` to close files. File objects that are still open when Python exits are automatically closed. Even if Python doesn't this for some reason, the OS would do it anyway.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!